# Persistent RAM variables in NIOS II

Tags: c, variable, nios-ii

I would like to define a C variable in RAM which can survive a CPU reset in NIOS II IDE. Something like `__persistent` in PIC world or `__no_init` in Renesas world.

Is there a similar keyword for NIOS compiler, which is based on `gcc`?

Comment: In order to have a complete question first you need to identify the compiler, is it gcc?  You may need to do this manually creating a section in the linker script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIOS uses a GCC variant, so you can use the GCC style attributes to place a variable in the `.noinit` section which basically forgoes any initialisation of the variable. e.g.

```
char someVar __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));
```

The RAM is not cleared during a NIOS processor reset, and GCC wont initialise the value of it, so the variable should survive.

It wouldn't however survive a full FPGA reset/reconfigure as that would reinitialise the RAM entirely. To cope with that you would need external SRAM.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the variable in `.noinit` section [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180892/force-gcc-to-forgo-zeroing-certain-globals) to be the right way to do it. However, `.noinit` section is missing in auto-generated NIOS linker file, so I had to add it manually:

```
.noinit (NOLOAD):
{
    PROVIDE (_alt_partition_noinit_start = ABSOLUTE(.));
    *(.noinit .noinit.*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE (_alt_partition_noinit_end = ABSOLUTE(.));
} > onchip_memory2_0
```

The important part is the `(NOLOAD)` directive which tells the linker that it shouldn't include any initialization code for this section.

Of course, the content of the on-chip RAM will be lost during reconfiguration or when its reset signal is asserted.